# How to download file from CentOS server on terminal through ssh server

Tags: ssh

Recently, I started working on a CentOS server and got access via ssh. I have root privilege through ssh. How can I download a file from server into my PC and upload to another server through ssh?

Comment: For one file it won't matter, but using `rsync` has many advantages over `scp`.

Comment: I noted. Thanks you [rsync](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=rsync)

Answer (score 4):

**Use scp command to upload a file**:

> scp [local-path] [username]@[hostname/ip]:[remote-path]
>   
> example:

```
scp /etc/example.file user@example.com:/etc/example
scp /etc/passwd user@10.0.0.1:/etc/passwd
```

**To download a file**:

1. You have a webserver installed on your server.
Place your file under website's root directory

> example:
>
> website:http://example.com
>
> remote file location:
>   /webroot/example.file

```
wget http://example.com/example.file
```

2. No webserver installed

> scp [username]@[hostname/ip]:[remote-path] [localpath]
>
> example:

```
scp user@example.com:/etc/passwd ./passwd
scp user@10.0.0.1:/etc/passwd ./passwd
```

IF you use iTerm2,it uses **an awesome way** to handle file upload/download through ssh client with a single right click: see here:[**iTerm2-shell-integration**](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html)

Comment: Thanks you so much I used scp.
scp root@example.com:[folder,path,etc..] ~/Downloads
It's syntax download into folder Downloads in PC
And easy to upload to another server.

Answer (score 0):

`scp` is what are you looking for.

Copy file from remote host (example.com) to ~/Downloads on your computer

```
scp root@example.com:/tmp/file ~/Downloads
```

.. and from your computer to a remote host (into home dir)

```
scp /tmp/file root@example.com:~/
```

Comment: I used scp. winscp is really nice tool